# How to make a simple yes/no popup in ASP.NET that return the result back to my c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

With ASP.NET, how do I prompt the user for a yes/no question and getting the result back to my .ascx?

So far I can open a confirmation dialog with use of Javascript, but I can't return the value. But I don't know if this is the right approach.

Comment: C# doesn't have a message box like in windows forms C#. That's why the javascript message boxes are used

Comment: asp.net doesn't have, to be more precise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use standart JavaScript `confirm()` function to show popup and do Post Back in case of Yes or No. For example:

```
if (confirm('Question')) {
    __doPostBack('', 'Yes_clicked');
} else {
    __doPostBack('', 'No_clicked')
}
```

Then on server in `Page_Load()` method do:

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    var result = Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
}
```

You can also do it async by specifying the first parameter of `__doPostBack()` function as ID of any update panel.

Comment: Great! __doPostBack was just what I was looking for. And actually __EVENTARGUMENT was pretty handy to know also. First tests shows that it works great.

Comment: :) Glad to help. Do not forget to accept if of all of your tests is passed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good practice to do this. you can get your confirm using javascript and postback or callback result to server.

but if you want to do this, this will help you :

[A Simple ASP.NET Server Control: Message Box & Confirmation Box](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/NingLiangSimpleControl.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

add this in head of source

function confirm_Edit()
    {
  if (confirm("Are you sure want to Edit?")==true)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
    }

call it like this

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using webforms, another solution could be the AJAX Control kit. Simply create a ModalPopup and have you confirm buttons inside that.

Read more here:
http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax, or to make a postback to the server.
Your c# code is server side and the javascript is client side.
If you use the ajax extensions for asp .net you can use [javascript page methods](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx):

```
PageMethods.YourMethod(confirm('your text'), OnSuccess, OnFailure);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this. As far as I know it prevents the rest of the button event from executing.

```
btnMyButton.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return confirm('Are you really sure?')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to show yes/no:

```
<script>     
        function AlertFunction() {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save this thing into the database?')) {
               $('#ConfirmMessageResponse').val('Yes');
            } else {
                $('#ConfirmMessageResponse').val('No');
            }
        }
    </script>
```

to handle it from .net side:

```
string confirmValue = ConfirmMessageResponse.Value;
                if (confirmValue == "Yes")
                {...}
```

Answer (score -1):

string confirmValue = ConfirmMessageResponse.Value;
showing error in this line when using in .net side

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).