# YES OR NO MessageBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to I display a confirm message box before deleting records? Buttons should be `YES` or `NO` only. Not `OK` or `CANCEL`. I have this code but it only works for c# winforms...

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Delete record no. " + numID.Text + "?", "Confirm User Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //codes to delete records
}
```

Comment: you need to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms library and you have to refer it in your program  like -> using System.Windows.Forms; Statement.

Comment: Depends on the technology you are using, a good recommendation would be to use Javascript's confirm function. Please embed it into your code to let the user decide and then continue to your action. There is a [similar question about it here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5867618/428813). [Here is some more light](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp). [And a good example in this link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Server-Side-Yes-No-Confirmation-Box-using-JavaScript.aspx). Hope it helps,

Comment: I'm getting this error `The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Comment: You don't want to use a Windows.Forms.MessageBox.  Don't be silly.

Comment: doesn't have yes/no options

Comment: The accepted answer to the following question has a jquery solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are displaying this client side, then you should use Javascript.  A good way to do this is to use the jQuery [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) method.  For example:

Markup:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm">This is the content</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:280,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Yes": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "No": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
 });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghLpV/

Answer (score 1):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function Confirm() {
            var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
            confirm_value.type = "hidden";
            confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
            if (confirm("Do you want to save data?")) {
                confirm_value.value = "Yes";
            } else {
                confirm_value.value = "No";
            }
            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server" OnClick = "OnConfirm" Text = "Raise Confirm" OnClientClick = "Confirm()"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Check this link:

http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Server-Side-Code-Behind-Yes-No-Confirmation-Message-Box-in-ASPNet.aspx