# How to make a dialog in asp.net using vb.net and java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, alert

In my asp.net website,i want to show a notification to the user when he/she try to delete data , i have used a msgbox in my vb code but it didn't work on the server side , i have  searched and found that i should use java script alert ,i have used it but the problem is that it appears  at the top of the screen and its so simple how can i make an alert or dialog like the following image using java script and vb

[image]

this is my code

```
 Protected Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click

   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType,Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('you cannot delete this data ')", True)

  End Sub
```

Please  any one can help me , any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show/display message box in C# asp.net forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655132/how-to-show-display-message-box-in-c-sharp-asp-net-forms)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a dialog box is not built into asp.net. You need to either just use the javascript `alert` / `confirm` functions, create the dialogbox yourself using html or import a GUI-library such as JQuery UI.

Here is a guide on how to use JQuery UI dialog, which I have used many times in ASP.NET: https://cmatskas.com/how-to-use-jquery-dialog-as-confirm-dialog-in-asp-net/

Comment: Thanks for your help , can we improve  the  design of the java script alert and make it more customized without using jQuery ?                          you have any idea how the alert design using this jQuery would be ? is it like the one in the image that i have posted ? since I want to make  a styled alert

Comment: No, you cannot do any changes to the javascript alert; the behavior is "hard wired". 

If you want to create the dialog your self using html, css and javascript you usually create your own html `div` or `span` that you may show or hide and functions like a dialog. To explore the options please look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655132/how-to-show-display-message-box-in-c-sharp-asp-net-forms

About Jquery dialog:look at the jquery dialog page https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ for examples and customization options.

(Sorry for not getting back earlier, I've had vacation.)