# MessageBox continues automatically without pressing on button

Tags: c#, messagebox, dialogresult

I have a messagebox with two buttons and a text.
This is the relevant code:

```
var result = MessageBox.Show("just a text","just a title",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Warning,System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification | System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign);
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    ... code ...
}
```

My problem is that the program enters the code inside the "if" automatically and the pop up message box doesn't even show up.
Even when i debug it I see that the code goes to the "if" row and the result is DialogResult.OK.

I am using web forms and ASP.Net.

the namespace for the MessageBox is "System.Windows.Forms".

I tried clearing the cache and even iisreset.

What else could help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you call `MessageBox.Show()` from ASP.NET?

Comment: Is this web application? You need to show messagebox using client side script. Not the server side code. What is the namespace of your `MessageBox` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am using web forms and ASP.Net.
>
> the namespace for the MessageBox is "System.Windows.Forms".

Don't do that. An ASP.NET site runs at the server, so there's nobody who can click the `MessageBox` if it even would pop up on the server.

If you want to show a popup to the user, it'll have to be in Javascript. See [How to make a simple yes/no popup in ASP.NET that return the result back to my c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867589/how-to-make-a-simple-yes-no-popup-in-asp-net-that-return-the-result-back-to-my-c).

Comment: So what do you recommend me to do? I can't run the poop up in the client side because it is activated from inside a column in a grid as a button.

Comment: You certainly can. Something with `RegisterClientScriptBlock`, try searching.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here.
In the code logic, the MessageBox **Show** method is concurrent with the main thread. So when running the **Show** method immediately the codes after it runs, and the main thread does not wait for the answer!
If you want to be the main thread wait for closing message, you should use the **ShowDialog** function of MessageBox. ([MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/39wcs2dh(VS.80).aspx))

But now you're working In the ASP, and this is very different from Windows, as our dear friend [CodeCaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster) also said, ASP the server side not the client side! So your message will be displayed on the server system, not on the user system who are watching your web site!

Comment: `MessageBox.Show()` is modal. :) It says so in the second paragraph of your link: _"Dialog boxes that display important messages should always be modal. The About dialog box in Visual Studio is an example of a modal dialog box. `MessageBox` is a modal form you can use."_, and at [MessageBox Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx): _"Displays a message window, also known as a dialog box, which presents a message to the user. It is a modal window, blocking other actions in the application until the user closes it"_.