# How to add yes or no message in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

first i am new in programming
i tried to add message inside my code but i did not succeed any way
what i need is to add message and when user say yes some action will do when no other actions will do.
i tried it in C# and succeed with messagebox but i have no idea to do it with asp.
my c# code was

---

```
            else if (MessageBox.Show("Do any vessel's permeate TDS more high than others", "High Vessel TDS?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                this.frmROPro.lbProblems.Items.Add("You have problem No 10");
            }
            else if (MessageBox.Show("Do feed water has some Metallic particles", "Metallic particles in the feed water?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                this.frmROPro.lbProblems.Items.Add("You have problem No 11");
            }
            this.frmROPro.lbProblems.Items.Add("You have problem No 9");
```

---

and that is where i need the code in asp

---

```
        if (currentitem("Permeate_Pressure") > currentitem("Reject_Pressure"))
        {
            addingproblem("No_12");
        }
        else if (**********i need the code here***************)
```

Comment: The ASP.NET programming model really differs from the WinForms programming model. You better invest some time in trying some tutorials and look up some web/http basics.

Comment: Take a look at https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a simple yes/no popup in ASP.NET that return the result back to my c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867589/how-to-make-a-simple-yes-no-popup-in-asp-net-that-return-the-result-back-to-my-c)

Comment: i found some solves depending like ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock but scriptManager not active with me

Comment: `MessageBox.Show` is a WinForms message box & runs only in server-side, you need to use JS `confirm` method for client-side display.